# Evaluate the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{2^x}{2^{(2^x)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{2^x}{2^{(2^x)}}dx$$

**My Try:**

substituting $t = 2^x$ we get:

$$\ln 2 \int_2^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^t dt = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 0.5} \left( \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\infty - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \right)$$

Apparently $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 0.5} = -1$ so we get that the integral equals $\frac{1}{4}$.

But that's a false proof.

Where is my mistake and how to correct that?

Thanks.

Comment: What different it would make? $(1/2)^n \to 0$.

Comment: $ln(2)$ goes into denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$t=2^x$,$x=\frac{\ln t}{\ln 2}$,thus $dx=\frac{1}{\ln2}\frac1tdt$, I'm afraid the integral should be 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{2^x}{2^{(2^x)}}dx=\frac{1}{\ln 2} \int_2^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^t dt $$

Comment: Yes, and the final answer is $\frac{1}{ln(2) ln(0.5)}\times (0-\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: @Arashium Thanks. But the rest is plain to see.

Comment: Just for his verification :)

Comment: Hey @vim, thank you. I hope that's not rude but would you mine looking at another answer of mine? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126519/160028

Comment: Hello @Elimination , I'm sorry but I have just taken one semester's course in analysis and this problem is quite beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y =2^{2^{x}}$, then $\ln y=2^{x} \ln 2$ and
$\frac{d y}{y}=2^{x} \ln ^{2} 2 d x=\ln ^{2} 2\left(2^{x} d x\right)$

The integral is transformed into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac{d y}{y^{2} \ln ^{2} 2} \\
&=\frac{1}{\ln ^{2} 2}\left[-\frac{1}{y}\right]_{4}^{\infty}\\
&=\frac{1}{4 \ln ^{2} 2}
\end{aligned}
$$